# Facebook Graph API PHP 2.10 not returning email address

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get user details using fb graph api version 2.10 but couldn't get the email address at all.. I tried searching in google but not got any answer for 2.10.

My code is below:

```
require 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
  // 'default_access_token' => 'qRkpJ79uoLmP6EU649rXAx4bZHs', // optional
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper(); 

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

try {
  // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
  // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name,website,work', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
print_r($me);
```

Comment: Did you ask the user for the necessary permission? Do they have a verified e-mail set in their profile?

Comment: yer it was a permission issue and ive fixed that now!

Comment: How you fixed it?